# Is semi-direct product uniquely defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

The definition of a semi-direct product is:

Let $H, N$ be 2 groups, $\alpha:H\longrightarrow Aut(N)$ be a homomorphism and $\cdot :H\times N\longrightarrow N$, $n\cdot h=\alpha(h)(n)$ be the corresponding action, then $*:(N\times H)\times (N\times H)\longrightarrow N\times H$ where $(n_{1},h_{1})*(n_{2},h_{2})=(n_{1}(\alpha(h_{1})(n_{2})), h_{1}h_{2})$ is the associative binary operation such that $(N\times H, *, (e_{N}, e_{H}))$ is group. It is the semi-direct product, denoted as $N\rtimes_{\alpha}H$.

My question: Since $\alpha$ is not explicitly defined here, does this mean that $\alpha$ is not unique? So the semi-direct product of two groups is also not uniquely defined?

Comment: The semidirect product takes as input the triple $(H, N, \alpha)$ consisting of two groups and an action of one on the other. It obviously depends on the choice of action, and if you choose a different action you will get non-isomorphic groups in general. But given all three pieces of input the result is a uniquely defined group.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. I have one more question. I sometimes see "prove that the semi-direct product of A and B is isomorphic to C" in my homework. If $\alpha$ is not uniquely defined, then how do I know which semi-direct product I should use?

Comment: $C$ should have a normal subgroup $N$ isomorphic to $A$, and the quotient $C/N$ will be isomorphic to $B$. If you have those isomorphisms $\phi$ from $N$ to $A$ and $\psi$ from $B$ to $C/N$, then one choice for $\alpha$ is this: if $b\psi = cN$, and $\gamma:N\rightarrow N$ is conjugation by $c$, then let $b\alpha = \phi^{-1}\gamma\phi$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260844/semi-direct-product-g-cong-n-rtimes-varphi-k?rq=1 for more details

Comment: @MichaelHartley But for $C$ to be isomorphic to as semidirect product of $A$ and $B$, you also need $N$ to have a complement in $C$.

Comment: @Irene: that depends on how you're being given $A$ and $B$ but if they're given as subgroups of $C$ then you could be being asked to prove that $C$ is the *internal* semidirect product in which case the action of one group on the other is given by conjugation in $C$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_semidirect_product_definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semi-direct product involves more than just two groups - it also requires, as you've correctly noticed, a group homomorphism.

And indeed, two different group homomorphisms may give us different semi-direct products, even non isomorphic semi-direct products. To see that note that the the trivial $\alpha(x)=id$ homomorphism gives us the standard direct product. You now just have to pick an example which is not a direct product. For example there are non-abelian semi-direct products of two abelian groups, e.g. there is a non-abelian semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In fact there are 4 non-isomorphic groups of order $16$, and each one is a semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (including the direct product).